# ERROR ITMS-90283: Invalid Provisioning Profile error for macCatalyst with Universal Purchase

Tags: swift, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

I am trying to submit a new app developed by macCatalyst and by using the same universal purchase option in the appstoreconnect.

- I enabled the new option use IOS Bundle identifier in XCode 11.4
- So, my IOS and Mac version of apps use the same bundle identifier
- I enabled the mac platform in appstore connect

I can build, run and archive my project successfully but when I try to upload or validate it I get the following error at the end of the upload:

```
ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.XXX.XXX [com.XXX.XXX.pkg/Payload/XXX.app] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal."
```

[image]

I get this error only when I upload macCatalyst version of my app. There's no problem about uplading and/or validating the IOS version.

I've already tried, deleting and redownloading of all profiles, refreshing automatic signing, refreshing entitlement file but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the items enabled under "Signing and Capabilities" in Xcode is the same as in [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list)

Xcode 11.4.1 added some extra when I added macOS as target, after removing the ones the app didn't use the ERROR ITMS-90283 error went away.